# Find a group that contains elements $a$ and $b$ such that $|a|=2, |b|=11$ and $|ab|=2.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

I was initially thinking along the lines of either finding some $S_n$ or some $D_n$ based on examples I saw here.

But the question is which of these $S_n$ or $D_n$ would be correct, and what would be the value of $n$.

Is $n = 11$, or is $n$ a multiple of $11$ and $2$?

Comment: $D_{11}$ (the dihedral group of the $11$-gon) will work. Of course, $S_{11}$ contains subgroups isomorphic to $D_{11}$ so it will also work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$|a|=2$ means $a^2 =1$, so $a=a^{-1}$. Same for $|ab|=2$: $abab=aba^{-1}b=1$ so $aba^{-1}=b^{-1}$.

This is exactly (one of) the definition(s) of the [dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group#Other_definitions)! Unluckily, you can find both notation $D_{11}$ and $D_{2 \times 11} = D_{22}$ in the literature for the* same group you are searching: check Wikipedia to understand what notation you are using.

*the dihedral group is the easiest example to find such $a,b$